# can you add Nested if Statements in else?

Tags: javascript

can you add Nested `if` Statements in `else` in javascript?

```js
if (condition === true) {
  
} else {

  if(condition === true) {
  
  } else {
    
  }
  
}
```

Comment: yes, but it actually makes no sense.

Comment: You can add a nested statement, but it makes sense only if the second statement verifies another condition, not the same one. Also you can use the shorter version: 
`if(condiction1) {
} else if(condition2) {
} else {
}
`
with same result

Comment: Can…? Yes, you can. You just did. You can put this code in a script file, a REPL, Node.js, wherever, and see that it’s working fine. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, sure you can, and it even makes sense as long as you are checking for different conditions.

However, this reads much more natural:

```js
if (condition1) {
  //  Your code running if condition1 === true
} else if (condition2) {
  //  Some other code running if condition2 === true
} else {
  //  Code running for all other cases
}
```

*Always avoid nesting if possible.*

*Also, there is no point in checking if a condition === true, as in itself it represents a boolean value.*

There is also something to be said for never using else at all... But you can google and read about that to your own leisure.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use an encapsulation pattern. Extract the logic elsewhere, so your main function remains easy to read.

```js
function checkFooEdgeCase(condition){
  return condition === "foo" ? "do foo stuff" : "do other stuff" 

function foo(condition) {
  if (condition === "true") return "do stuff" 
  return checkFooEdgeCase(condition) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. consider the example below:

```js
let sum = 35;
if (sum % 10 == 0){
    console.log("a");
} else if (sum % 2 == 1){
    if (sum % 5 == 0 && sum % 2 == 0){
        console.log("b");
    } else if (sum % 5 == 0){
        console.log("c")
    } else {
        console.log("d")
    }
} else {
    console.log("e")
}
```

More examples and explanation here: https://exlskills.com/learn-en/courses/javascript-fundamentals-basics_javascript/conditional-statements-zgrXFcSqdfIF/the-if-statements-YcHrGQKxvTOI/nested-if-statements-nSAoxbDFvMOq

Comment: I woudn't recommend this solution with a lot of `else if`, because too much nested conditions can make the function difficult to read and to debug. With an encapsulation pattern, you can separate responsibilities and keep a clean main function.